# automate npm update,bower prune, bower update inside gulpfile as gulp tasks

Tags: npm, gulp

I want to automate my gulpfile with the following tasks(gulp.task).

1. npm update
2. bower prune
3. bower update

Every time anyone changes package.json and bower.json, I just run gulp and the packages get installed/updated/deleted without having to run these commands through terminal.

Comment: So what's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use plugins like [gulp-install](https://github.com/slushjs/gulp-install) to do this... or you can write the task yourself like below

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var bower = require('bower');

gulp.task('bower', function(cb){
  bower.commands.install([], {save: true}, {})
    .on('end', function(installed){
      cb(); // notify gulp that this task is finished
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this worked. One question, how do i do npm prune through gulp-task. gulp-install seems to have only install command but no prune/uninstall commands.

Comment: gulp-install will do both install/uninstall... prune i m not sure

Answer (score 5):

there is another easier way to do this (thought this is not inside gulp file)

in your package.json add `update` command in scripts section

```
"scripts": {
    "update": "npm install && npm prune && bower install && bower prune",
    "first-run": "npm install -g gulp bower && npm run update"
},
```

and then from command line do:

```
 npm run update
```

you can also create command like `first-run` as shown above and run it like

```
npm run first-run
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do all three: update/install/prune for both npm and bower, so I ended up creating a tool for that: [updatejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/updatejs).

Please let me know if you like it :)